# Saving array to postgres in Rails raises ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4.0.1 with postgres I have an activerecord column stored as an array

```
create_table "accounts", force: true do |t|
  t.string "schedule_days", default: [], array: true
end
```

I can assign an array just fine.

```
agent.schedule_days = agent.schedule_days << 1
 => [1]
```

But the save does not persist.

```
agent = Account.last
agent.save
BEGIN
COMMIT
```

Some of the forums suggested that the ActiveRecord needs the column to be dirtied so:

```
agent.schedule_days_will_change!
 => [1]
```

This causes the SQL statement to change but it raises an ArgumentError.

```
agent.save
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "schedule_days" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 
WHERE "accounts"."type" IN ('Ghost') AND "accounts"."id" = 6543  
[["schedule_days", [1]], ["updated_at", Wed, 27 Nov 2013 03:56:14 UTC +00:00]]
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2): UPDATE "accounts" SET "schedule_days" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."type" IN ('Ghost') AND "accounts"."id" = 6543
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK 
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Comment: Turns out it was an outdated activerecord adapter causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` is begin used rather than the default `postgresql` adapter provided by Rails. There may be an updated version of the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` that supports arrays.

Comment: Brilliant!  Updated from 0.6.3 to 0.6.5 and it works.